# how to insert multi-checkbox value if they are checked in db in php

Tags: php, database, checkbox

I want to save the value of the checkbox that is checked in db in php. there are many checkbox here and I want to save the value of the selected checkbox. how can I handle it?

```
<html>

  <body>
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1">
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2">
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3">
      .
      .
      .
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1000">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: put all input in `form` tag and when you submit the form ,you will get an array only with all  selected checkboxed values

Comment: put in form and submit.. you will get the array of checkboxes that were checked, then you can either save them in one column comma separated or in other table using a loop

Answer (score 0):

Create a form and put them all inside the form. When someone submits the form you will get an array of values having **category** KEY.

So your HTML code will look like this, Assuming you will be using **POST** method.

```
<html>

  <body>
     <form method="POST" action="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1">
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2">
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3">
      .
      .
      .
     <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1000">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

And you can get the values in PHP like,

```
$category_values=$_POST["category"];
print_r($category_values); // for testing purpose, to know the selected checkboxes.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code do like this:

```
<?php 
$categories = $_POST['category'];
for($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++){
     $category = $categories[$i];    
    //insert query should comes here
    mysql_query("insert into table value($category)");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php 
$categories = $_POST['category'];

foreach($categories as $row) {

 //insert query 

"insert into table(column_name) values('$row')";

}
 ?>
```